# filter products in React

Tags: reactjs, filter, tailwind-css

I have a project to do in React, I chose to do a shopping site, I have a list of products, I have created the product.jsx page where on the left hand side I have multiple filters. As far as I tried, I don't get to see the filtered products.

```
<div className="border-t border-gray-200 px-4 py-6">
          <h3 className="-mx-2 -my-3 flow-root">
            
            <button type="button" className="flex w-full items-center justify-between bg-white px-2 py-3 text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-500" aria-controls="filter-section-mobile-0" aria-expanded="false">
              <span className="font-medium text-gray-900">Gender</span>
            </button>
          </h3>
          
          <div className="pt-6" id="filter-section-mobile-0">
            <div className="space-y-6">
              <div className="flex items-center">
                <input id="filter-mobile-gender-0" name="gender[]" value="men" type="checkbox" className="h-4 w-4 rounded border-gray-300 text-indigo-600 focus:ring-indigo-500" onChange={handleGenderCheckboxChange}/>
                <label for="filter-mobile-gender-0" className="ml-3 min-w-0 flex-1 text-gray-500" >Men</label>
              </div>
              <div className="flex items-center">
                <input id="filter-mobile-gender-1" name="gender[]" value="women" type="checkbox" className="h-4 w-4 rounded border-gray-300 text-indigo-600 focus:ring-indigo-500" onChange={handleGenderCheckboxChange}/>
                <label for="filter-mobile-gender-1" className="ml-3 min-w-0 flex-1 text-gray-500" >Women</label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: could you post product.jsx full code to your question?

Comment: i've managed to do it, thanks!